# Drag and drop rows in a table with respect to another table

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hey I have two tables with equal number of rows. For example if I try to sort a row (say row-3) in a tableOne, the exact row (row-3) in other table(tableTwo) should also be sortable. Is there any way to achieve this.

I have noticed Sortable Jquery UI wwidget, where we can drag and drop  rows with in the table or in to another table when we have two tables. But my case different as stated above.  please let me know any work around.

Answer (score 2):

I already worked on this before seeing it was put on hold, so I'll just add the updated jsfiddle. Brief explanation, used window mouseover event to move the tableTwo row around, using offsets computed from tableOne to tableTwo position differences. In sortable start event, keep track of the moving rows, which can be used in window mouseover event. Then, in sortable change event, move the placeholder around in tableTwo to reflect the change in tableOne. Finally, on sortable beforeStop event, reset the "state" saved in sortable start event.

https://jsfiddle.net/s73adk01/10/

JS

```
$(".tableOne tr").each(function (idx) {
    if (idx > $(".tableTwo tr").length) 
        return;
    var $tableTwoTr = $(".tableTwo tr").eq(idx);

    $(this).attr("data-row-id", idx);
    $tableTwoTr.attr("data-row-id", idx);
});

var isDragging = false;
var $rowToDrag = null;
var $curUIHelper = null;
var $curPlaceholder = null;
var $curTableTwoPlaceholder = null;

$(window).on("mousemove", function () {
    if (!isDragging)
        return;

    var topDiff = $(".tableOne").offset().top - $(".tableTwo").offset().top;
    var leftDiff = $(".tableOne").offset().left - $(".tableTwo").offset().left;

    $rowToDrag.css("position", "absolute");
    $rowToDrag.offset({ 
        top: $curUIHelper.offset().top - topDiff,
        left: $curUIHelper.offset().left - leftDiff
    });
});

$(".tableOne tbody").sortable({
    start: function(e, ui) {
        isDragging = true;

        var rowId = $(ui.helper).attr("data-row-id");

        $rowToDrag = $(".tableTwo tr[data-row-id='" + rowId + "']");

        $curUIHelper = $(ui.helper);
        $curPlaceholder = $(ui.placeholder);

        $curTableTwoPlaceholder = $curPlaceholder.clone();
        $curTableTwoPlaceholder.insertBefore($rowToDrag);
    },
    change: function(e, ui) {
        var $placeholderNextRow = $curPlaceholder.next();

        if ($placeholderNextRow.length <= 0) {
            // At the end
            $curTableTwoPlaceholder.insertAfter($(".tableTwo tbody tr").last());
        }
        else {
            var nextRowID = $placeholderNextRow.attr("data-row-id");

            var $tableTwoNextRow = $(".tableTwo tr[data-row-id='" + nextRowID + "']");

            $curTableTwoPlaceholder.insertBefore($tableTwoNextRow);
        }
    },
    beforeStop: function(e, ui) {    
        isDragging = false;

        $rowToDrag.css({
            position: "static",
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });

        $curTableTwoPlaceholder.remove();

        $rowToDrag = null;
        $curUIHelper = null;
        $curPlaceholder = null;
        $curTableTwoPlaceholder = null;

        var rowId = $(ui.helper).attr("data-row-id");

        var newPosition = $(".tableOne tr:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)")
            .index($(ui.helper));

        var $tableTwoRowToMove = $(".tableTwo tr[data-row-id='" + rowId + "']");

        if (newPosition == 0) {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertBefore($(".tableTwo tr").first());
        }
        else {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertAfter($(".tableTwo tr").eq(newPosition));
        }

        // Flash so we can easily see that it moved.
        $(ui.helper)
            .css("background-color", "orange")
            .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);

        $tableTwoRowToMove
            .css("background-color", "yellow")
            .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1500);
    }
});
```

***Original answer:***

May be a "cleaner" way to do this, but this gets the job done. The idea is to give each row in each table a "row id", and on sortable's beforeStop event, get the position of the moved element from tableOne, find the corresponding row in tableTwo by row id, then move tabelTwo's row to the same position that tableOne row moved to.

https://jsfiddle.net/s73adk01/4/

HTML

```
<table class="tableOne">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table class="tableTwo">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(".tableOne tr").each(function (idx) {
    if (idx > $(".tableTwo tr").length) 
        return;
    var $tableTwoTr = $(".tableTwo tr").eq(idx);

    $(this).attr("data-row-id", idx);
    $tableTwoTr.attr("data-row-id", idx);
});

$(".tableOne tbody").sortable({
    beforeStop: function(e, ui) {        
        var rowId = $(ui.helper).attr("data-row-id");

        var newPosition = $(".tableOne tr:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)")
            .index($(ui.helper));

        var $tableTwoRowToMove = $(".tableTwo tr[data-row-id='" + rowId + "']");

        if (newPosition == 0) {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertBefore($(".tableTwo tr").first());
        }
        else {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertAfter($(".tableTwo tr").eq(newPosition));
        }

        // Flash so we can easily see that it moved.
        $(ui.helper)
            .css("background-color", "orange")
            .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);

        $tableTwoRowToMove
            .css("background-color", "yellow")
            .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1500);           
    }
});
```

Comment: That's good. May work my for my case, before I try a small question: Currently you are changing the row based on the row movement in a table. Is there any chance that we can make the row as well move along with other, while we do drag and drop.

Comment: I believe so, I think you will need to do it on the window mousemove event, as I'm not sure if sortable has "built in" way a to do that.