# How to work sortable table synchronously on two different tabs (jQuery datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

How I can work sortable table synchronously on two different tabs  (jQuery datatables).

Here is my [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/urashita/jm8s3nt0/43/)

```
$(function() {
    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();    
    $( "#summary_body, #detail_body" ).sortable().disableSelection();
});
```

If you changed order in summary tab, I would like to change order automatically in detail tab.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite similar solution to my questions.

[Drag and drop rows in a table with respect to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994953/drag-and-drop-rows-in-a-table-with-respect-to-another-table)

However, these JSFiddle answer does not work fine if I tried to drag one row and drop it to upper place.

Here is my fix. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ctbypx5/39/)

```
var curPosition;
$(".tableOne tbody").sortable({
 start: function (e, ui) {
    curPosition = $(".tableOne tr:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)")
                .index($(ui.helper));
    },
beforeStop: function(e, ui) {    
    var rowId = $(ui.helper).attr("data-row-id");

    var newPosition = $(".tableOne tr:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)")
        .index($(ui.helper));

    var $tableTwoRowToMove = $(".tableTwo tr[data-row-id='" + rowId + "']");

    if (newPosition == 0) {
        $tableTwoRowToMove.insertBefore($(".tableTwo tr").first());
    }
    else {
        if (curPosition > newPosition) {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertBefore($(".tableTwo tr").eq(newPosition));
        } else if (curPosition < newPosition) {
            $tableTwoRowToMove.insertAfter($(".tableTwo tr").eq(newPosition));
        }
    }

    // Flash so we can easily see that it moved.
    $(ui.helper)
        .css("background-color", "orange")
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);

    $tableTwoRowToMove
        .css("background-color", "yellow")
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1500);

}
});
```